# Can't hit my end point with 2 post methods

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm really struggling with trying to hit a single end point in my ASP.NET Core Web API app

The relevant parts of the `Controller` are

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class PlanController : BaseApi
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/{controller}/Clear/")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Clear()  //always returns 404
    {     //some code in here
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromBody] PlanPoco model) //works as expected
    {//more code
    }
```

and the relevant part of my Startup.cs file

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "api",
                pattern: "{api}/{controller}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();

        });
```

In postman, I would expect to type in `https://localhost:12345/api/plan/clear/` and for this to match the end point. It does not. It always returns a 404

Can anyone give me some advice here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, you apply attribute routing `[Route("api/[controller]")]` on your controller and `[Route("api/{controller}/Clear/")]` on `clear` action, to make request to clear action method, you should use below URL.

```
https://localhost:port/api/plan/api/plan/clear
```

> I would expect to type in https://localhost:12345/api/plan/clear/ and for this to match the end point.

To achieve your requirement, you can try to apply `[HttpPost("Clear")]` to your `Clear` action method.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class PlanController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("Clear")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Clear()   
    {     //some code in here
        return Ok("Clear Action");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromBody] PlanPoco model) //works as expected
    {//more code
        return Ok("Post Action");
    }
}
```

Or modify the code like below.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Clear")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Clear()  //always returns 404
{
```

Test Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you try like and make same request ;

```
  [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class PlanController : BaseApi
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Clear()  //always returns 404
    {     //some code in here
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromBody] PlanPoco model) //works as expected
    {//more code
    }
```